# Move non-adjacent column values to a new tab in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

I am looking for a way to basically recreate the query(import function within Google Sheets, but using an Apps Script.  The reason I'm unable to use a formula is because there may be some manipulation to the data once it moves across to it's relevant tab, further down the line.  Which isn't possible to do with formulas.

I have a Google Form and the form branches off to ask different questions based on a cluster selection.  Therefore, in the sheet the responses output to, the data isn't necessarily all together for each tab.  (I'm unable to share the exact one due to work policies but I created a dummy sheet as an example).
In the example, the pink/red columns would be transferable across all clusters, but then only the relevant cluster information would go with it.  I.e. for Cluster 2, I would need to transfer columns A-D and G-H.
[Example Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kj4k7.png)

I have a script that copies consecutive columns, but I'm not sure how to move non-consecutive

```
function copyTo() {
var sSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var srcSheet = sSheet.getSheetByName("Form responses 1");
var tarSheet = sSheet.getSheetByName("Cluster 2");
var lastRow = srcSheet.getLastRow();

for (var i = 3; i <= lastRow; i++) {
var cell = srcSheet.getRange("B" + i);
var val = cell.getValue();
if (val == "Cluster 2") {
  
var srcRange = srcSheet.getRange("A" + i + ":H" + i);
  
var tarRow = tarSheet.getLastRow();

var tarRange = tarSheet.getRange("A" + (tarRow+1) + ":H" + (tarRow+1));
  
srcRange.copyTo(tarRange);
  
}
}};
```

Any help would be appreciated! If I haven't explained myself clearly, please let me know and I will try to update.

Thanks so much

Comment: Please share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output. Whenever possible, you need to include a minimal example that reproduces the issue. You can also include the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ, that would be helpful as well. Please visit [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.

Comment: Thanks Lorena, I will bear in mind those pieces of information next time however I'm unable to share sheets due to corporate blocks.  The best I could do was a screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to skip some columns in range you take from responses sheet. If, so you can try something like this:

```
function copyToAnotherSheet() {
  var rng1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange(2,1,3,10).getValues();
  var targetSheet = "Sheet2";
  var rng2FirstRow = 1;
  var rng2FirstColumn = 1;
  const skipNumbersArr = [2,3,5]; ///// numbers of columns to be skipped, change this!
  const skipNumbers = [];
  skipNumbersArr.forEach((item) => {
    skipNumbers.push(item - 1);
  });

  const outputArr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i<rng1.length; i++){
    var temp = [];
    for (var j = 0; j<rng1[0].length; j++){
      if (skipNumbers.indexOf(j) == -1){
        temp.push(rng1[i][j]);
      }
    }
    outputArr.push(temp);
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(targetSheet).getRange(rng2FirstRow, rng2FirstColumn, outputArr.length, outputArr[0].length).setValues(outputArr);
}
```

Just set the values for rng1, targetSheet, rng2FirstRow, rng2FirstColumn, skipNumbersArr...